# Filtering an Option Result using a boolean Result in Rust

Tags: rust, asynchronous, optional

I'm trying to rewrite one of my pet projects in Rust, and when I was faced with the problem of filtering a `Result<Option<T>, E>` via a `Result<bool, E>`, I couldn't figure out what the best approach was.

Since I'll be doing the same thing many times throughout the project I need something that's generic while also being readable, so the solution I came up with was to implement my own traits.

My first case is to write a function that can be used to authenticate a user; by first querying the users based on the e-mail address, and then checking if the stored, encrypted password matches the plain text one retrieved from the request.

For that purpose I have the following functions:

```rust
trait AccountRepository {
  async fn find_by_email(&self, email: &String) -> Result<Option<AccountModel>, CoreApiError>;  
}

trait PasswordEncoder {
  fn verify(&self, plain: &String, encoded: &String) -> Result<bool, CoreApiError>;
}
```

And by combining both, I'd like to return a `Result<AccountModel, CoreApiError>`. When the inner `Option<>` is empty or the passwords don't match I'd like to return a `CoreApiError` that says the account was not found, and when the inner `Option<>` is non-empty and the passwords match, I'd like to return the `AccoutModel` instance that was found. If either function returns a `CoreApiError` I can just return it directly because I'm not really interested in it.

To that end I implemented the following traits:

```rust
pub trait FilterInner<T, F: FnOnce(&T) -> Result<bool, CoreApiError>> {
  fn filter_inner(self, f: F) -> Result<Option<T>, CoreApiError>;
}

impl<T, F: FnOnce(&T) -> Result<bool, CoreApiError>> FilterInner<T, F> for Result<Option<T>, CoreApiError> {
  fn filter_inner(self, f: F) -> Result<Option<T>, CoreApiError> {
    let result = self?;
    let filtered = match result {
      Some(data) => {
        let is_ok = f(&data)?;
        if is_ok {
          Some(data)
        } else {
          None
        }
      }

      None => None,
    };
    Ok(filtered)
  }
}

pub trait EnsurePresent<T, E>
where
  E: Into<CoreApiError>,
{
  fn ensure_present(self, message_key: &str) -> Result<T, CoreApiError>;
}

impl<T, E> EnsurePresent<T, E> for Result<Option<T>, E>
where
  E: Into<CoreApiError>,
{
  fn ensure_present(self, message_key: &str) -> Result<T, CoreApiError> {
    let maybe_data = self.map_err(|e| e.into())?;
    match maybe_data {
      Some(data) => Ok(data),

      _ => Err(CoreApiError::not_found(message_key)),
    }
  }
}
```

...and used them in the following fashion:

```rust
pub async fn initiate_login(&self, command: &InitiateLogin) -> Result<AccountModel, CoreApiError> {
  self
    .account_repository
    .find_by_email(&command.email)
    .await
    .filter_inner(|account| self.password_encoder_port.verify(&command.password, &account.password))
    .ensure_present("account.not.found")
}
```

At this point I'm pretty happy with the result, because overall I like sweeping complex stuff under the rug as long as I can provide readable and easy to use interfaces. Plus, I'd rather prefer chaining function calls than nesting `match` statements, so this is perfect for my needs.

That said I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it. All throughout the process I couldn't help but think that there should be something I can use to do this easily (probably involving `flat_map`), but since I lack the particular Rust experience I couldn't tell what that was.

As such I'm open to any opinions, critiques, and suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `.await?`?

Comment: I'm already using `.await` to extract a `Result<Option<T>, E>` out of the asynchronous `find_by_email(...)` method, so the issue here is more about filtering the value contained in *that* `Result<>`.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that you don't need to do that if you use `.await?` instead of `.await`

Comment: Whoops sorry, I missed the `?` at the end. As I mentioned in my post I'm trying to avoid any `match` statements because I think I should be able to navigate within the same higher-kinded type without explicitly unwrapping it (e.g. using `?` to extract the value part of a `Result`). 

The traits I came up with essentially do the same thing, and that's exactly why I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve the same result, without unwrapping any `Result`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
pub async fn initiate_login(&self, command: &InitiateLogin) -> Result<AccountModel, CoreApiError> {
  self
    .account_repository
    .find_by_email(&command.email)
    .await
    .filter_inner(|account| self.password_encoder_port.verify(&command.password, &account.password))
    .ensure_present("account.not.found")
}
```

The challenge with this code is determining what `filter_inner` and `ensure_present` do. They aren't standard rust methods nor are they named according to a standard convention. But what's to be done about that?

One possibility is to use the `?` operator to early return any errors:

```
pub async fn initiate_login(&self, command: &InitiateLogin) -> Result<AccountModel, CoreApiError> {
  self
    .account_repository
    .find_by_email(&command.email)
    .await?
    .try_filter(|account| self.password_encoder_port.verify(&command.password, &account.password))?
    .ok_or_else(|| CoreApiError::not_found("account.not.found"))
}
```

This takes care of the `Result`s simplifying the need for special functions on `Result<Object<T>>`. I do invoke an imaginary `try_filter` method, but I think that method is simpler fits into standard rust naming conventions, it very well could be a method on `Option`.

Another possiblty to consider is to just use Rust's ability to do logic on patterns and don't try to make everything use higher order functions.

```
pub async fn initiate_login(&self, command: &InitiateLogin) -> Result<AccountModel, CoreApiError> {
  let account = self
    .account_repository
    .find_by_email(&command.email)
    .await?;

   if let Some(account) = account {
      if self.password_encoder_port.verify(&command.password, &account.password)) {
         Ok(account)
       } else {
         Err(CoreApiError::not_found("account_not_found"))
       }
   } else {
       Err(CoreApiError::not_found("account_not_found"))
   }
}
```

But, it seems you don't really want to use the ? operator or pattern matching.

> I think I should be able to navigate within the same higher-kinded
> type without explicitly unwrapping it (e.g. using ? to extract the
> value part of a Result).

My own assessment is that the `?` operator/pattern matching are handy tools, and you shouldn't be trying to avoid them. But to each their own. You could use methods on `Result`.

```
pub async fn initiate_login(&self, command: &InitiateLogin) -> Result<AccountModel, CoreApiError> {
  self
    .account_repository
    .find_by_email(&command.email)
    .await
    .and_then(|account| account.try_filter(|account| self.password_encoder_port.verify(&command.password, &account.password)))
    .and_then(|account| account.ok_or_else(|| CoreApiError::not_found("account.not.found")))
}
```

This avoids the `?` operator and mostly sticks to the standard functions. But it is a bit messier.

Another possibility is something like `NullableResult` from `nullable-result` crate. It defines a type which combines the functionality of `Option` and `Result`.

```
pub async fn initiate_login(&self, command: &InitiateLogin) -> Result<AccountModel, CoreApiError> {
  self
    .account_repository
    .find_by_email(&command.email)
    .await
    .try_filter(|account| self.password_encoder_port.verify(&command.password, &account.password)))
    .result_with(|| CoreApiError::not_found("account.not.found")))
}
```

The methods defined on `NullableResult` can perform the natural actions for results of options. This means that you can just use those methods. But its a little inconvenient to have to `NullableResult` instead of `Result<Option<>>`

What you've done is defined operations on `Result<Option<T>>`. The tricky part to that is picking good names for the methods. It would be nice to have a sensible naming convention that made it clear. For example, iterators have `try_***` methods and `itertools` provides `***_ok`. These methods operate on iterators over `Results`. It'd be nice if there was good word to indicate that these methods operate over `Result<Option<...>>`

If you go down this route, I'd suggest having only one trait, something like `ResultOption` which is defined for any `Result<Option<T>>` and provides all of the utility methods you might want for options in results. This would replace your two separate traits for the two distinct methods.

Part of the logic of your filtering function can use the methods on result:

```
  fn filter_inner(self, f: F) -> Result<Option<T>, CoreApiError> {
    self.and_then(|result| match result {
             Some(data) => f(&data).map(|is_ok| if is_ok { Some(data) } else { None }),
            None => Ok(None),
    })
  }
```

Alternately, you could go all in on the match statements:

```
  fn filter_inner(self, f: F) -> Result<Option<T>, CoreApiError> {
    match self {
      Ok(Some(data)) => {
        match f(&data) {
          Err(error) => Err(error),
          Ok(true) => Ok(Some(data)),
          Ok(false) => Ok(None)
        },
      Ok(None) => Ok(None),
      Err(error) => Err(error)
    }
  }
```

This method seems very niche:

```
fn ensure_present(self, message_key: &str) -> Result<T, CoreApiError>;
```

Would it perhaps make more sense to have a generic method for turning Nones into errors which took a closure to define the error?